# C - Pointer Arithmetic causing problems as opposed to standard [] way

Tags: c

I'm new to C and learning it for a class right now. We are currently working on a little project and we are supposed to use pointer arithmetic to access arrays as opposed to the standard [] way.

For some reason, I can use it just fine on the first loop (see code) but when I use it in the second, it doesn't produce the same outcome as if I were to use the standard [] way.

```c
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            int num = *(*array+i)+j;
            //Irrelevant code
         }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            int num = array[j][i]; // Error comes if I do *(*array+j)+i;
            //Irrelevant code
         }
    }
```

I don't know if I am missing something here but why would calling the array using pointer arithmetic be different between the 2 loops?

Comment: The first loop is doing `array[i][0] + j`. `Error comes` What error? Please post the full error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equivalence between subscripts and pointer notation is:

```
a[i] == *(a + i)
```

You are using `(*a + i)` in place of the correct `*(a + i)`.

I believe your first set of loops should read:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        int spot = *(*(board+i)+j);
        for (int k = j + 1; k < size; k++) {
            if (spot == *(*(board + i) + k) && spot > 0) {  
                 return 0; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, since you've not provided an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
— or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)
— the same idea by a different name), I can't easily test the code.

Also, now you know why it is better to use the explicit subscript notation; it is a lot harder to get it wrong.